# Disable conversion of unicode to emotify icons in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, emoticons

I understand that new emotify icons has been added to iOS 7.0. Is there a way to disable the conversion of Emotify icons from unicode in iOS 7?

Comment: Does this question pertain to in your own app or in texting/emails?

Comment: @John: I'm guessing texting. I want to know how to disable the auto-conversion too.